# Emulator on tizen studio is not working

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

when Launching Emulator in Tizen studio for mobile V3.0 emulator screen shows **The Emulator is still running.only the display has been switched off** message or black screen.Also when launching BasicUI native app on the emulator it shows error `java.io.IOExecption`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing the Home button as suggested [here](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/problem-tizen-emulator-manager).

Comment: thanks, it works but when I run my app on the emulator, studio still shows `java.ioIOExecption`.

Comment: That looks like a different problem. It's hard to answer it without seeing your code. Perhaps you could create a new question for this, if needed.

Comment: created : [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511299/java-io-ioexecption-in-tizen-studio)

Comment: Thank you! This makes things easier.