# java.io.IOExecption in tizen studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

while running BasicUI app as native app in Tizen emulator, it shows the error `java.io.IOExecption`.My java jdk version is 8.

Answer (score 0):

Please Confirm You not are Deploying to an Lower API version Device.

For Example:

A 'Tizen 3.0 Wearable Native Project' to 'Tizen 2.3.2 Wearable Emulator'.

Comment: My device is M-3.0-x86 and Api version is 3.0

Comment: Can you launch the Emulator ? Is it Responding ? (Without deploying the App )

Comment: I got the solution.I have enabled hardware virtualization in the BIOS.Now it is not giving this error and emulator is also working fine.

Comment: Please Describe the question in more details, And add your solution as answer & accept that answer.